multispectral drone imagery processing - orthomosaic reflectances
I want to compute NDVI and other spectral indices from Phantom 4 Multispectral flights.
What would be the optimal Open Drone Map processing settings to obtain valid reflectances (in the range of 0-1) values? How is this related to the output format (e.g. 32 float vs 16bit unsigned integer)? Do I need to normalize/scale somehow the output to obtain reflectances?
I’d appreciate some guidance! At a loss with so many processing options - first time using drone imagery! Pixel values in the bands of the orthomosaic include negative values and other very small ones (like commented in this thread: Multispectral orthomosaic reflectance values). Details on processing options and bands statistics below.
Thanks in advance for your advice and processing tips! Cheers!

opendronemap/odm /dataset --min-num-features 24000 --orthophoto-resolution 1 --dem-resolution 1 --radiometric-calibration camera+sun --texturing-skip-global-seam-leveling --orthophoto-no-tiled --orthophoto-compression DEFLATE --skip-3dmodel --use-exif

In the 32-Float output, band stats are:
+Band 1 Red
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0.00034588208654895
STATISTICS_MEAN=4.1638241700016e-05
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=3.9477168852232e-05
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 2 Green
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0.00023238248832058
STATISTICS_MEAN=4.305794611104e-05
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=3.0363897633484e-05
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 3 Blue
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=9.4602539320476e-05
STATISTICS_MEAN=1.9053275863524e-05
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=1.234490200541e-05
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 4 NIR
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0.0004375149437692
STATISTICS_MEAN=9.3793929263158e-05
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-3.2635998650221e-05
STATISTICS_STDDEV=6.0245358047185e-05
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 5 RedEdge
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0.0004199493851047
STATISTICS_MEAN=8.9436464517462e-05
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-4.1719085857039e-05
STATISTICS_STDDEV=5.8862251313409e-05
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

For the record, I have also tried
2) --radiometric-calibration camera+sun, but then I get this message: ===== Done, human-readable information to follow… =====
[ERROR] Uh oh! Processing stopped because of strange values in the reconstruction. This is often a sign that the input data has some issues or the software cannot deal with it. Have you followed best practices for data acquisition? See Flying Tips — OpenDroneMap 3.5.4 documentation
100 - done.
ERROR: LoadError: failed process:
Process(docker run --rm -v /Users/ODM_jl/2023-10-31_plot_3_60mts:/dataset opendronemap/odm /dataset --min-num-features 24000 --orthophoto-resolution 1 --dem-resolution 1 --radiometric-calibration camera+sun --texturing-skip-global-seam-leveling --orthophoto-no-tiled --orthophoto-compression DEFLATE --skip-3dmodel --use-exif, ProcessExited(1)) [1]15:42

without radiometric calibration, I obtain pixel values in the range 0-65535 (16 bits unsigned output)

+Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65535
STATISTICS_MEAN=23895.357407019
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=13607.769200509
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 2
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65535
STATISTICS_MEAN=24560.449830254
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=13725.046988844
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 3
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65535
STATISTICS_MEAN=25780.406980453
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=13597.531125652
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 4
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65535
STATISTICS_MEAN=23270.148626075
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=13429.487557349
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

+Band 5
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65535
STATISTICS_MEAN=23583.155747676
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=13700.276507947
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0

[ODM]https://community.opendronemap.org/t/phantom4-ms-orthomosaic-reflectances/22061
